# Do I need to be online to play story mode?

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

Some time ago, I don't remember exactly when, GTA5 stopped running without Xbox Live. I have to connect to Xbox Live and then I can run GTA5. What happened? Do I always have to be connected?

Comment: We played through a lot of the campaign at my mates house. He does not even have an internet connection. Soo 100% yes. But you will get a better experience playing with online.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to be connected to xbox live to play the single player part of GTA5.

I don't have xbox live and i just happen to play GTA5 today without any problems.
However, i havn't had xbox live in over 2 years so i can't say if any setting are causing your problems or not.
I know some parts of GTA are suppose to be run through xbox live like the BAWLSAQ (sp?) part and such.

You should probably specify more what you mean with "it stopped running".
Are you getting error messages? if so; which?

Comment: No) I don`t have any error messages) When i`m trying to enter in GTA5, i see a message. Message asks me to enter in account , i enter , but without xbox live game won`t loading =/  Message.. Do you know, when you are entering in game without account and you need enter in. I enter but without xbox live game just doesn`t let me pass

Comment: Have you tried logging in first without any disc in the console and then starting the game?

Comment: Of course i have tried